# Data annotations on EF entities suddenly stopped working

Tags: c#, sqlite, data-annotations, ef-database-first

I've inherited a web application and the data annotations used to define relationships between entities suddenly stopped working.

I have tried various things and I can't figure out why hoping someone here can point the issue out.

The application uses a SQLite database, and contains three (3) basic tables:

- order
- order_entry
- order_client

The entity for **order** looks like this:

```
[Table("order")]
public class Order
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderEntry> OrderEntries { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual OrderClient OrderClients { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        OrderEntries = new HashSet<OrderEntry>();
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy. A single order can contain many entries, but a single order can only have a single client.

The entity code for **order_entry** looks like this:

```
[Table("order_entry")]
public class OrderEntry
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Again, nothing fancy. A single entry can only belong to a single order.

OrderEntries work well, and we can do some basic includes, without issues:

```
ctx.Orders.Include(x => x.OrderEntries).ToList();
```

The problem, however, comes in with the **order_client** table, in the many-to-one relationship with order.

The **order_client** entity:

```
[Table("order_client")]
public class OrderClient
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("order_id")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public OrderClient()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }
}
```

We've tried adding the **[ForeignKey("OrderId")]** attribute to "Orders", but this throws an exception saying that the property "OrderId" cannot be found on the parent role "order".

If we add the **[InverseProperty("Orders")]** attribute to the "OrderId" property, an exception is thrown that the column OrderClient_Id cannot be found in the table.

The **order_entry** and **order_client** tables have a foreign_key constraint with **order** in the database structure, we made sure of this.

I am completely stumped here. Unfortunately, we cannot move the current instance of the application to fluent API as the change impact outweighs the SLA agreement, so we need to fix the current problem.

Any ideas would be welcomed.

**UPDATE**

The original developer created the client - order relationship incorrectly. He stated a order can have multiple clients, instance of a single client having multiple orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the concept of relationship.
You can find help here. Try to go throught it once and you will be done.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that URL did not help us at all with database-first. We tried what they teach there with code-first and it works, but we have an existing database with data we cannot lose, so we turned code-first off, and this does not work with database-first, at least, that's why I'm here.

Comment: the URL itself didn't help, but you pointed out the problem and I couldn't see it at first. Thanks for you help, really appreciate it.